# One server running Django (with Nginx and Apache) and Wordpress Blog

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, virtualhost, wordpress, django

I have nginx listening to port 80 for my primary site foo.com.  It proxys to port 8080 which is where the Django app lives

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name www.foo.com foo.com;
  access_log /home/jeffrey/www/ddt/logs/nginx_access.log;
  error_log /home/jeffrey/www/ddt/logs/nginx_error.log;
  location / {
   proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
   include     /etc/nginx/proxy.conf;
  }
  location  /media/ {
   root /home/jeffrey/www/ddt/;
  }
  location  /static/ {
   root /home/jeffrey/www/ddt/;
  }
  location  /public/ {
   root /home/jeffrey/www/ddt/;
  }
}
```

I'd like to have a wordpress blog run on the same server.  Apache is listening to port 8080 with this http.conf file

```
NameVirtualHost *:8080
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/jeffrey/www/ddt/apache/ddt.wsgi
WSGIPythonPath /home/jeffrey/www/ddt

<Directory /home/jeffrey/www/ddt/apache/>
<Files ddt.wsgi>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Files>
</Directory>
```

I added my Wordpress site using a virtualhost

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
ServerName www.bar.com
ServerAlias bar.com
DocumentRoot /home/jeffrey/www/jeffrey_wp
</VirtualHost>
```

When I go to bar.com I still see my django app.  Is it possible for these two sites to run on the same server?

Comment: Why do you do this so complicated? You can serve the Django app directly with nginx.

Answer (score 0):

You will see it if you navigate to bar.com:8080.

IMHO you should use Nginx as a reverse proxy for both sites foo.com and bar.com.
Use Apache to serve the Django site and the Wordpress site from ports 8080 and 8090